What are the reasons to have /bin in PATH post usr merge?
Debian has recently merged /bin and /usr/bin, that is, /bin is now a symlink to /usr/bin. However, the default PATH defined in /etc/login.defs still contains both directories:
ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

This leads to duplicates when all directories in PATH are searched. For example:
$ type -a ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls

$ ( IFS=:; grep -rlI '^#! */bin/sh' $PATH ) | grep apt-
/usr/bin/apt-key
/bin/apt-key

Thus it would be nice to remove /bin and /sbin from PATH, but since this hasn't been done I assume there's some, perhaps subtle, reasons why. So, what would be the consequences of removing these directories from PATH?

I’m not aware of any reason not to remove the paths, I think it’s just a case of the maintainers not getting round to it. There’s a pending patch to remove /bin and /sbin from the default paths in login.defs.
